# Radio button validation in javascript for multiple screens

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some help on how to validate radio buttons generically across multiple screens and make the script reusable. I have manage to get it working by using a single class **$('.radio_validate')**. However, if I want to reuse the script for any other pages I would have to duplicate the script which is not ideal.**(I'm not super familiar with JS so appreciate any support on this.)**

Here's the code specifically on the radio button validation. Basically adding the error class if not checked and remove the error class if checked. Ideally, I would like to make **$('.radio_validate')** into something that is reusable if possible.

```
if( $('.radio_validate').is(':visible') && !$('.radio_validate').is(':checked') ){
                $('.radio_validate')
                    .closest('.form__item')
                    .addClass('error');
                shakeCurrentCard( $('.radio_validate').closest('.step') );
                //return false;
            }
            else {
                $('.radio_validate')
                    .closest('.form__item')
                    .removeClass('error');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on having every single radio button validated no matter the page, then use:

`$("input[type='radio']")`

However, if you don't want all of the radio buttons to be validated, then adding a class or data-attribute, to the radios you want validated is the best option.

**loops through the radio instead of doing them all at once:**

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible') && !$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this)
      .closest('.form__item')
      .addClass('error');
    shakeCurrentCard($(this).closest('.step'));
    //return false;
  } else {
    $(this)
      .closest('.form__item')
      .removeClass('error');
  }
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your input @imvain2, I did try that method $("input[type='radio']") before but it turns out to validate all the radio buttons all at once. (I use one html file to display multiple cards and each card will ask one question with some radio buttons. Perhaps you could shed some light on how to add class or data attribute to validate the radio buttons separately?

Comment: @Jason L, for class, I’m referring to what you are already doing. Adding a class to the radio buttons that you want to have required.

Comment: @JasonL I updated my answer, I think your problem is you aren't looping through them.

Comment: @imavin2, the way I setup the html is that each section is a card containing some radio buttons. My question is that if I add a class to the radio buttons would it not validate all the radio buttons across multiple cards?